# Query Custom Post by Category

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, categories, loop

I try to query custom post type called `news` by a category called `Alumni` with `ID=160`.

When I use such arguments, as a result, I get all my custom posts **without** `Alumni` category:

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'news',
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'category__not_in' => 160
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
...
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

However, changing `category__not_in` to `category__in` gives an empty list but I would expect the opposite of the initial result. I can't really understand where I make a mistake.

Also, I tried using `cat` and `category_name` instead and I played around with different categories but results were always the same.

In my research I came across `'tax_query'` but I can't get it to work as well. The documentation is not quite clear for me.

Answer (score 5):

Are these custom taxonomies or the regular categories?

if they are just categories you should use:

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'news',
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'category_name' => 'Alumni'
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
...
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

if you want to use it by id

use:

```
'cat' => 160
```

instead of

```
'category_name' => 'Alumni'
```

Comment: I didn't register any custom taxonomies. I only created some categories in the admin panel. The problem is using `category__not_in` works as expected (returns all custom posts **without** my category assigned to). Using the opposite: `cat` or `category_name` always return empty lists. Is my thinking good here that switching between `cat` and `category__not_in` should show me the opposite results?

Comment: That's correct thinking.   Remember cat is for ID and  category_name is the name Not the slug.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like this in the array,  Had a similar problem earlier which this solved.

```
'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy_name',
```

Or something like :

```
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy_name',
        'terms' => 'Alumni',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'include_children' => true,
),
```

Comment: `taxonomy` returns all of my custom post types. I quickly played around with `tax_query` settings you proposed but I always got empty list :(

edit: also, just a quick note. In the last example there shouldn't be `category__not_in`. Maybe someone coming here in the future won't get confused :)

Answer (score 0):

## To get custom post type posts with specific category use custom taxonomy

Register the taxonomy name of the custom post type like categories and then assign a category to each post when you added new post.
Here is the example of the code

```
  add_action( 'init', 'news_my_taxonomy');
  function news_my_taxonomy(){
 // custom post type taxonomies
    $labels = array(
    'name' => 'Categories',
    'singular_name' => 'Category',
    'add_new' => 'Add Category',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Category',
    'all_items' => 'All Categories',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Item',
    'new_item' => 'New Item',
    'view_item' => 'View Item',
    'update_item' => 'Update Category',
    'search_items' => 'Search Categories',
    'not_found' => 'No record found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No items found in trash',
    'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Item',
    'menu_name' => 'Categories'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'news_category'),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        );
        register_taxonomy('news_category', array('news'), $args);
}
```

## then

## create taxonomy template page 'taxonomy-news_category.php'

and add the query to get the posts with this category name

```
   $cat_name = single_cat_title;
   $args = array( 'category_name' => $cat_name, 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'post_type' => 'news', 'paged' => $paged);
```

All the work is done.Good luck